# getCTM fail coordinates

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg

Why is the use of matrix setCTM leads to the decrease and shift of coordinates? How to get the coordinates was accurate?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVGgVq

```
function btncircles(e) {
  var node = e.target;  
  var x = node.getAttribute("transform");
  var ctm = node.getCTM();
  var transform = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg").createSVGTransform();
  var matrix = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg").createSVGMatrix();
  var sa = ctm.a;
  var sd = ctm.d;
  matrix.a = sa;
  matrix.d = sd ;
  matrix.e = ctm.e;
  matrix.f = ctm.f;
  transform.setMatrix(matrix);
  node.transform.baseVal.initialize(transform);
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] and translate in the actual question, or this could be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I'm working on it. I've re-created the scale decrease and shift of coordinates. What behaviour do you expect or want when your circle is clicked?

Comment: I had hoped to get the current matrix, i.e. the current size of the circle and when mousehover to increase the scale of 1.3, when mouseout reduce to 1 scale. But the use of getCTM leads to decrease range, although in this example it was expected that the reduction should not happen

Comment: I see. Does that mean that, after posting this on Feb 4, you switched your strategy to [the question you posted Feb 12](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35361691/5218951), which addresses the same issues (re-scaling while mousing in and mousing out) using svg's `animateTransform`? If so, no problem, but I won't put any more effort into this. However, let me know if you still want this question figured out.

Comment: Yes I changed the path of attainment. The only thing I would like to know why getCTM gives the changed coordinates , it is a bug of the browser ? or feature work? The idea is because getCTM should give the current matrix? Thank you!